# Rails 4 - datetimepicker-rails gem, datepicker not disabling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datepicker, datetimepicker

I am using the datetimepicker-rails gem (https://github.com/zpaulovics/datetimepicker-rails)

I would like to have a simple timepicker, but datepicker is always present.
I tried with using the "format" option, the "pickDate: false" option but it is still there.
What am I doing wrong?

Here is the sample of my view:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@hour, html: {class: 'form-inline'}, remote: true) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>
<div class="row form-inputs">
  <%= f.input :start_time, as: :time_picker, autocomplete: :off %>
  <%= f.input :end_time, as: :time_picker, autocomplete: :off  %>
</div>
<div class="form-buttons">
  <%= f.button :submit, "Zapisz", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <%= link_to '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" title="Wstecz">Wstecz</button>'.html_safe, hours_path %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

and in coffee script I have

```
$(document).ready -> $('.time_picker').datetimepicker XXX
```

where XXX was one of the options I tried: `format: "H:i"`, `format: "LT"` or `pickDate:false`.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Paulina

Answer (score 1):

I think I saw this in
http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#bootstrap-3-datepicker-v4-docs

In the **Custom Format** part.

Comment: Hey, I saw that too. In fact they use the option "format: 'LT'", which is not working for me.